# Marionette controller.listenTo not capturing event

Tags: marionette, backbone-events

I'm having a weird problem with some Backbone Marionette controller in a sub-application module.

I cannot make it to work capturing one of its view events with the "controller.listenTo(view, 'event', ...)" method, although the "view.on('event',...)" works no problem.

Here is the sample code for the module views :

```
MyApp.module("SubApp.Selector", function (Selector, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    "use strict";

    // Category Selector View
    // ------------------
    // Display a list of categories in the selector

    // Categories list item
    Selector.CategoryOption = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
        template:   "#my-category-template",
        tagName:        "option",
        onRender: function () { this.$el.attr('value', this.model.get('id')); }
    });

    // Categories list container
    Selector.CategoryListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
        template:   "#my-category-list-template",
        tagName:        "div",
        id:     "categories",
        itemView:   Selector.CategoryOption,
        itemViewContainer: "select",
        events: {
            'change #category_items': 'categoryClicked'
        },
        categoryClicked: function() {
            var catID = this.$('#category_items').val();
            console.log("category clicked "+catID);
            this.trigger("category:changed", catID);
        }
    });

    // Selector Component Controller
    // -------------------------------
    Selector.Viewer = Marionette.Controller.extend({
        initialize: function (_options) {
            this.region = _options.region;
            this.collection = _options.collection;
        },
        show: function () {
            var view = new Selector.CategoryListView({ collection: this.collection });
            this.listenTo(view, 'category:changed', this.categoryChanged);
            //view.on('category:changed', this.categoryChanged, this);
            this.region.show(view);
        },
        categoryChanged: function (_category) {
            console.log("category changed in controller");
        }
    });
});
```

Is there anything I got wrong about event listening from a controller object ?

Shouldn't I use the listenTo syntax as is seems to be recommended widely for proper event handling and listener destruction ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code should work. If you could put up a jsFiddle, it would help track down the issue. Regarding `listenTo`, it's particularly useful for views, because you can call `myView.stopListening` before closing it and therefore avoid zombies.

Comment: Thanks David for spending time on this...

Comment: I finally made it through, building it up again from a simpler App boilerplate... It was a bit over complicated to get all of this on a jsFiddle. The issue was : I was using various components(modules) with a single property only to hold them all. Making a "show" on each of them would replace the previous referenced component with the new one for that property in my main controller. Things were showing up OK but event bubbling was broken (and I don't even mention garbage collection and zombie stuff I would have had to further deal with...). Anyway thanks again David for your effort.

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved your problem!